# Separating FloatingActionButton to another file

Tags: flutter

I'm just picking up flutter. I'm trying out a simple tutorial which will display the face of two dice. When I click on the floating action button, it will randomise the numbers on both dice. I took it a step further to separate the FAB into another file. My problem starts when i try to pass the onPressed event to my custom FAB file from the main file.

In my rollDice method, I'm unable to call setState which complains about instance members cant be accessed from static method. Not very sure how to move on from here.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'custom_floatBtn.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

final swatch = const {
50: const Color(0xff661f00),
100: const Color(0xff992e00),
200: const Color(0xffcc3d00),
300: const Color(0xffe64500),
400: const Color(0xffff4d00),
500: const Color(0xffff5e1a),
600: const Color(0xffff824d),
700: const Color(0xffffa680),
800: const Color(0xffffc9b3),
900: const Color(0xffffede6)
};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xffFF5722, swatch),
    //primarySwatch: Colors.green,
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Dice Betting'),
);
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

final String title;

@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
static int leftDiceNumber = 1;
static int rightDiceNumber = 1;

static void rollDice() {
Random num = Random();

setState(() {
  leftDiceNumber = num.nextInt(6) + 1;
  rightDiceNumber = num.nextInt(6) + 1;
});
}

static String param = 'Roll';

static final customFloatBtn = new CustomFloatBtn(
butname: param,
onPressed: rollDice,
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
    body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Image.asset('dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Image.asset('dice$rightDiceNumber.png'),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: customFloatBtn
    // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build 
    methods.
    );
    }
    }
```

CustomFloatBtn class

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class CustomFloatBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String butname;

  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;

  CustomFloatBtn({this.butname, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FloatingActionButton(
  tooltip: 'Increment',
  //child: Icon(Icons.add),
  child: Text(butname),
  onPressed: onPressed,
  );
  }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you making them `static`

Comment: If i dont make rollDice method static, dart will complain "Only static members can be accessed in initializers"

Comment: @KishanLathigara please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561) before suggesting edits again. That use of code blocks is nearly abusive

Comment: @Zoe I can maintain the editing policy next time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are not using simple implementation like this. Remove `static` from everywhere.

```
floatingActionButton: CustomFloatBtn(
  butname: param,
  onPressed: rollDice,
),
```

---

Update:

```
void rollDice() { // remove static from here
  Random num = Random();

  setState(() {
    leftDiceNumber = num.nextInt(6) + 1;
    rightDiceNumber = num.nextInt(6) + 1;
  });
}

String param = 'Roll'; // remove static from here

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: CustomFloatBtn( // use CustomFloatBtn here
      butname: param,
      onPressed: rollDice,
    ),
    ...
}
```

Comment: If i do that, there in error in the declaration for param and rollDice. "Only static members can be accessed in initializers"

Comment: Have you removed `static` from everywhere?

Comment: Yes removed from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Make everything non-static. All your variables and functions are class level only and you will not access them outside of your class.

So, remove static everywhere from your Main.dart file and simply do what CopsOnRoad did in his answer.

Here is the modified code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'custom_floatBtn.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

final swatch = const {
50: const Color(0xff661f00),
100: const Color(0xff992e00),
200: const Color(0xffcc3d00),
300: const Color(0xffe64500),
400: const Color(0xffff4d00),
500: const Color(0xffff5e1a),
600: const Color(0xffff824d),
700: const Color(0xffffa680),
800: const Color(0xffffc9b3),
900: const Color(0xffffede6)
};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xffFF5722, swatch),
    //primarySwatch: Colors.green,
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Dice Betting'),
);
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

final String title;

@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
int leftDiceNumber = 1;
int rightDiceNumber = 1;

void rollDice() {
Random num = Random();

setState(() {
  leftDiceNumber = num.nextInt(6) + 1;
  rightDiceNumber = num.nextInt(6) + 1;
});
}

String param = 'Roll';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
    body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Image.asset('dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Image.asset('dice$rightDiceNumber.png'),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: CustomFloatBtn(
                               butname: param,
                               onPressed: rollDice,
                        );
    );
    }
    }
```

Comment: Assigning customFloatBtn constructor to floatingActionButton did it! Thanks!